# Sub Menu visible before hover Plus Sub Menu background uses Parent Hover background

Tags: html, css, hover, parent-child, submenu

I am hoping that I can get some fresh eyes on this. I know I made a rookie coding mistake somewhere here but I just can't seem to find it and my eyes are going cross-eyed. Please help.

So the sub menu is staying visible even before the hover AND for some reason the background of each sub menu item is taking on the parent hover background properties and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I did [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eb5FH/35)

Here is the code in case you don't want to visit the link

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul>
        <li class="style13"><a href="#"><strong>Option 1</strong></a></li>
        <li class="style13"><a href="#"><strong>Option 2</strong></a></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Comments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu {
width: 740px;
height: 60px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
background: #000033 url(images/menu-wrapper-bg2.png) repeat-x left top;
}

#menu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

#menu ul li {
float: left;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#menu ul li a {
display: block;
float: left;
height: 60px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px 36px 0px 36px;
line-height: 60px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #00033;
font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;    
font-size: 23px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #FFFFFF;
border: none;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #0000FF;
}

#menu .current_page_item a {
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #0000FF;
background: #000066;
/* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #000066 0%, #000033 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #000066 0%, #000033 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #000066 0%, #000033 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, 
#000066), color-stop(1, #000033));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #000066 0%, #000033 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000066 0%, #000033 100%);
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
background: #000066;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #0000FF;
color: #FFFFFF;
/* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #000066 0%, #000033 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #000066 0%, #000033 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #000066 0%, #000033 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0,  
#000066), color-stop(1, #000033));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #000066 0%, #000033 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000066 0%, #000033 100%);
}
#menu ul li ul li.active a, #menu ul li ul li a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:#000066;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #0000FF;
}
#menu ul li ul {
height:500px;
left:289px;
overflow:visible;
position:absolute;
top:69px;
width:160px;
float: left;
}
#menu ul li ul li:hover ul li ul {
left:275px;
top:37px;
padding-top: 2em;
padding-left: .90em;
line-height: 30px!important;

}
#menu ul li ul li {
background: #000066;
border:1px solid #ffffff;
float:none;
height:29px;
margin:-1px 0 0;
padding:0 12px;
position:relative;
width:auto;
z-index:1000;
}
#menu ul li ul li a {
color:#ffffff!important;
font-family:'Abel', sans-serif; 
font-size:20px;
line-height:22px;
text-transform:none;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #0000FF;
font-weight:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:block;
padding-top: 5px;

}
#menu ul li ul li.active a, #menu ul li ul li a:hover {
color:#fff!important;
line-height: 30px!important;

}
```

Comment: Are  you hiding the sub-menu before the hover?  I can't see it if you are?

Comment: I had tried it but everything always disappeared. I didn't put it in right though because the answer below was totally the answer. However, I am still having problems with the sub menu items taking on the properties of the parent hover background. If you have any ideas on that, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That CSS doesn't actually hide or reveal the sub menus. Try adding this:

```
#menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! That worked on hiding it before the hover. Thank you! Any ideas as to why they sub menu items are taking on the parent hover background and line height?

Comment: Have you defined anything diferent? Remember that `ul li` will affect ALL `li` whether submenu `li` or not.

Comment: Yes, but when I assign it as ul li ul li, that should change the sub menu properties. It usually does in other sub menus that I have worked on. This is actually code I have used on a different site with no problems and the sub menu does not take on the parent hover properties at all.

Comment: not sure. When I adjust the first rule in your `#menu ul li ul li` declaration to `background: red;` the submenu has a red background. http://jsfiddle.net/Eb5FH/58/